# Spring MVC: Bind from form:option to enum

Tags: spring-mvc

I am looking to bind from my select box in my form to a particular enum.

Consider this enum:

```
public enum OperatorDTO {
LESS_THAN ("<"),
GREATER_THAN (">"),
EQUALS ("="),
NOT_EQUALS("!=");

private String operator;

public String getOperator() {
    return operator;
}

private OperatorDTO(String operator)
{
    this.operator = operator;
}
```

and this snippet from my form:

```
<form:select path="rules[${counter.index}].operator">
    <form:options itemLabel="operator" itemValue="operator" />
</form:select>
```

The page renders fine and displays the various ">", "<" symbols in the drop-down box

However, when I submit my form I get errors when it attempts to bind the values back to the enums
e.g. "No enum const class com.fmrco.insight.adminconsole.dto.enums.OperatorDTO.<"

Is there an easy way to perform this binding?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try to omit `itemValue="operator"`.

Item value should be the name of enum constant, and as far as I remember it's a default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Form tags snippet is correct and enum is correct also. What is missing here is converter which Spring will use to convert String from `form:options` element to OperatorDTO `enum`.

**1)** Add two more methods to OperatorDTO enum

```
    // Enum level method to get enum instance by operator field.
    public static OperatorDTO getByOperator( final String p_operator ) {
        for ( OperatorDTO operatorDTO : OperatorDTO.values() ) {
            if ( operatorDTO.isOperatorEqual( p_operator ) ) {
                return operatorDTO;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    // Instance level method to compare operator field.
    public boolean isOperatorEqual( final String p_operator ) {
        return getOperator().equals( p_operator ) ? true : false;
    }
```

**2)** Create custom converter such this

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class OperatorDTOConverter implements Converter<String, OperatorDTO> {
    public OperatorDTO convert( String source ) {
        return OperatorDTO.getByOperator( source.trim() );
    }
}
```

**3)** Registeg converter in app configuration (**java config** in this case)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "your.base.package"} )
public class AppWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    public void addFormatters( FormatterRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addConverter( String.class, OperatorDTO.class, new OperatorDTOConverter() );
    }

    ...
}
```